# Manipulate strings in prolog

Tags: string, prolog

I have a list of stirings I need to manipulate and write out.
I get the strings the usual way with H|Tail recursion.
H will look something like "statement(foo, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5)"
I want to be able to write out only foo, foo2, foo3 on separate lines

out: foo

bar: foo2
...
...
div: foo5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert string to codes, codes to a term, then destructure the term:

```
/* SWI Prolog 
*/
read_from_string(String, Term) :-
    string_to_list(String, List),
    read_from_chars(List, Term).

demo:- 
    String="statement(foo, foo2, foo3,foo4,foo5)",
    read_from_string(String, Term),
    Term =.. [Fst,Snd,Thr|Rest],
    write(functor:Fst),nl,
    write(arg1:Snd),nl,
    write(arg2:Thr),nl,
    write(rest:Rest),nl.
```

Demo session:

```
?- demo.
functor:statement
arg1:foo
arg2:foo2
rest:[foo3,foo4,foo5]
true.
```

Choose the items to print according to their respective positions in the list that resulted from *univ*(=..). Here they were all printed.